# manual commits with @Transactional attribute

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I use spring+hibernate template to process entities. There is rather big amount of entities to be loaded all at once, so I retrieve an iterator from hibernate template.

Every entity should be processed as a single unit of work. I tried to put entity processing in a separate transaction (propagation = REQUIRED_NEW). However I ended with exception stating that proxy is bounded to two sessions. This is due to suspended transaction used for iterator lazy loading. I am using the same bean for lazy loading and for processing entities. (May be it should be refactored into two separate daos: one for lazy loading and one for processing?)

Then I tried to use single transaction that is committed after each entity is processed. Much better here, there are no exceptions during entity processing, but after processing is finished and method returns, exception is thrown from spring transaction managing code.

```
@Transactional
public void processManyManyEntities() {
    org.hibernate.Sesstion hibernateSession = myDao.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Iterator<Entity> entities = myDao.findEntitesForProcessing();
    while (entities.hasNext()) {
        Entity entity = entities.next();
        hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
        anotherBean.processSingleEntity(entity);
        hibernateSession.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

`processSingleEntity` is a method in another bean annotated with `@Transactional`, so there is one transaction for all entities. I checked what transaction causes an exception: it is the very first transaction returned from `hibernateSession.beginTransaction()`, so it just not updated in transaction manager.

There are several questions:

<strike>is it possible to avoid session bind exception without refactoring the dao?</strike> that is not relevant question as problem is with Session and hibernate not with dao

is it possible to update transaction in the transaction manager? **solved**

is it possible to use the same transaction (for `anotherBean.processSingleEntity(entity);`) without `@Transactional` annotation on `processManyManyEntities`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible to update transaction in transaction manager. All you need to do is get SessionHolder instance from `TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(sessionFactory)` and set transaction in the session holder to the current. That makes possible to commit transaction whenever it is necessary and allows transaction to be committed by spring transaction manager after method return.

Comment: Is it possibile to get an example? The solution is not very clear, but seems interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to remove the @Transactional annotation on "processManyManyEntities()", and, to eagerly load all data from "findEntitesForProcessing".

If your want each entity of data to be transactional in "processSingleEntity", the @Transactinoal on "processSingleEntity" is fine. You don't have to annotate the @Transactional on "processManyManyEntities()". But in case of lazy loading, eager loading is a necessary mean to prevent the source data from loading in another session, say, in "processSingleEntity".

Since the transaction for each entity of data, the transactional boundary in loading of source data is not the case of your transaction. Don't let the "lazy loading" to complicate your intent of transaction for modification of data.

Comment: I can not avoid lazy loading, I have thousands of entities.

Comment: Maybe you could try to process a couple of entries at a time, with eager loading. But it would be more clear if you can describe more detail about "findEntitesForProcessing". How much data would be processed in a entity for inside of "processSingleEntity".

Comment: Fortunately, there is a way to update transaction in the transaction manager. I have added an answer with details. Nice idea to load several entities eagerly! I would have used it if nothing was found! :)